# If $A$ and $B$ are $n \times n$ diagonal matrices, prove that so also is $A^pB^q$ for all positive integers $p, q$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification

> If $A$ and $B$ are $n \times n$ diagonal matrices, prove that so also is $A^pB^q$ for all positive integers $p, q$.

**My Proof**

Let $A = \begin{cases} 
      a_{i,j} & i = j \\
      0 & i \not= j 
   \end{cases}$

and

$B = \begin{cases} 
      b_{i,j} & i = j \\
      0 & i \not= j 
   \end{cases}$

be $n \times n$ matrices and $p, q$ be positive integers.

$\therefore [A^pB^q]_{i,j} = \sum_{k = 1}^n a^p_{i,k}b^q_{k,j} = a^p_{i,j}b^q_{i,j}$, where $i = j \ \forall n \ge i,j \ge 1$.

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to review my proof and provide feedback.

Comment: The proof is fine if you already have shown that if $A=\mathrm{diag}(a_1, \cdots, a_n)$ then $A^p=\mathrm{diag}(a_1^p, \cdots, a_n^p)$. That being said, why don't you prove the more general statement that if $A_1, \cdots, A_k$ are diagonal, then $A_1A_2\cdots A_k$ is diagonal (by induction with base of induction being $k=2$).

Comment: @Hamed Thanks for the assistance. I have taken your advice and posted my proof as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are making it more complicated than needed.

1. If $C$ and $D$ are diagonal, then (prove directly that) $CD$ is diagonal.
2. Then it follows inductively (which you may prove) that $A^p$ is diagonal (with $C= D = A$) for any positive integer $p$. (If $A^{p-1}$ is diagonal, then let $C= A^{p-1}$ and $D = A$, and use 1. concluding that $CD = A^p$ is diagonal.)
3. Hence, $B^q$ must also be diagonal for any positive integer $q$, from 2.
4. Use 1. with $C = A^p$ and $D = B^q$ which are diagonal by 2. and 3. to conclude that $CD = A^p B^q$ is diagonal.

Note that 3. and 4. are direct consequences of 1. and 2.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So are you saying that my revised proof is incorrect? Or just that it is over-complicated?

Comment: @ThePointer I could not follow it, and I think that is due to it being too complicating and imho unclear. In my instructions, you essentially just need to prove that a product of two diagonal matrices is diagonal (step 1.), and the rest follows thereupon.

Comment: What about now? I have added justifications for some steps of the proof.

Comment: @ThePointer I hate to put it this way, but your proof is just overall unclear to me. I can understand the line of argument, and it makes sense, but your making every line unnecessarily convoluted. I would suggest to remake the argument with my points.

Comment: Ok, now I see what you were referring to. 4. is where the simplification occurs, since this formulation of the proof doesn't require the many summations that my last proof required.

Answer (score 0):

I have taken Hamed's advice and formed (what I think is) a new and complete proof:

Let $A = \begin{cases} 
      a_{i,j} & i = j \\
      0 & i \not= j 
   \end{cases}$

and

$B = \begin{cases} 
      b_{i,j} & i = j \\
      0 & i \not= j 
   \end{cases}$

be $n \times n$ matrices and $p, q$ be positive integers.

We first prove that $A^p$ and $B^q$ are diagonal for all positive integers $p,q$ by induction.

Let $P(n) = A^n$.

$n = 1$: $ P(1) = A^1 = A = [a_{ij}]_{n \times n} = \begin{cases} 
      a_{i,j} & i = j \\
      0 & i \not= j 
   \end{cases}$

$n = p$: $P(p) = A^p = [A_1A_2...A_p]_{ij}$

$= \sum_{k = 1}^n \sum_{t = 1}^n ... \sum_{c = 1}^n a_{ik}a_{kt}...a_{cj}$ *By the definition of matrix multiplication.*

$ = a_{ij}^p \forall n \ge i = j \ge 1$ *Since all $a_{ij} = 0 \forall i \not= j$; and so we are left with the product $a_{ij}a_{ij}...a_{ij}$.*

Therefore, the induction hypothesis is $P(p) = A^p = a_{ij}^p \forall n \ge i = j \ge 1$

$n = p + 1$: $(A^p)A = (a_{ij}^p)A$ *By the induction hypothesis.*

$= (a_{ij}^p)(a_{ij})$ *Since $A$ is diagonal.*

$= a^{p+1}_{ij} \forall n \ge i = j \ge 1$

Q.E.D.

And we do the same for $B$ to show that $B^q$ is diagonal for all positive integers $q$.

We now prove that $A^pB^q$ is also diagonal.

$[A^pB^q]_{ij} = \sum_{k = 1}^n [A_1A_2...A_p]_{ik}[B_1B_2...B_q]_{kj}$ *Since the ($i-j$)th element of $[A^pB^q]$ is equal to $\sum_{k = 1}^n [A_1A_2...A_p]_{ik}[B_1B_2...B_q]_{kj}$ by the definition of matrix multiplication.*

$= \sum_{k = 1}^n \left[ \left( \sum_{t = 1}^n \sum_{c = 1}^n ... \sum_{f = 1}^n a_{it}a_{tc}...a_{fk} \right) \left( \sum_{t = 1}^n \sum_{c = 1}^n ... \sum_{f = 1}^n b_{kt}b_{tc}...b_{fj} \right) \right]$

*Since we have that $[A_1A_2...A_p]_{ik} = \sum_{t = 1}^n \sum_{c = 1}^n ... \sum_{f = 1}^n a_{it}a_{tc}...a_{fk}$ and $[B_1B_2...B_q]_{kj} = \sum_{t = 1}^n \sum_{c = 1}^n ... \sum_{f = 1}^n b_{kt}b_{tc}...b_{fj}$.*

$= \sum_{k = 1}^n (a^p_{ik})(b^q_{kj})$ *By the definition of matrix multiplication, and since $a$ and $b$ represent elements of diagonal matrices.*

$= a_{ik}^p b_{kj}^q \forall i = k = j$

$= a_{ij}^p b_{ij}^q$ Q.E.D.

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to review my proof and provide feedback.

---

**I will now formulate the proof in the way suggested by Sisyphus.**

1. If $C$ and $D$ are diagonal, then $CD$ is diagonal.

$C = [c_{ij}]_{n \times n} = \begin{cases} 
      c_{i,j} & i = j \\
      0 & i \not= j 
   \end{cases}$

and

$D = [d_{ij}]_{n \times n} = \begin{cases} 
      d_{i,j} & i = j \\
      0 & i \not= j 
   \end{cases}$

$[CD]_{ij} = \sum_{k = 1}^n c_{ik}d_{kj} = c_{ij}d_{ij} \forall i = j$ *Since, by the definition of diagonal matrices, we have that $c_{ik}d_{kj} = 0 \forall k \not= i = j$.*

Q.E.D.

We just proved that, if $C$ and $D$ are diagonal, then $CD$ is diagonal. We now use induction to prove that $A^p$ is diagonal, where $C = D = A$.

2. For every positive integer $p$ and $q$, $A^p$ and $B^q$ are diagonal.

Let $P(p) = C^{p - 1}D = A^p$ where $C = D = A$.

$P(1) = ID = D = A$ *As required.*

$P(k) = C^{k - 1}D = A^k$ *This is the induction hypothesis.*

$P(k + 1) = (C)(C^{k - 1}D)$ *Since $(C)(C^{k - 1}D) = (CC^{k - 1})(D) = C^kD$.*

$= (C)(A^k)$ *By the induction hypothesis.*

$= (A)(A^k)$ *Since $C = A$ is an assumption.*

$= A^{k+1}$ Q.E.D.

3. The same argument can be used for $B^q$ to show diagonality.
4. If $A^p$ and $B^q$ are diagonal, then $A^pB^q$ is also diagonal.

Let $C = A^p$ and $D = B^q$.

$C = [c_{ij}]_{n \times n} = \begin{cases} 
      c_{ij} & i = j \\
      0 & i \not= j 
   \end{cases}$

and

$D = [d_{ij}]_{n \times n} = \begin{cases} 
      d_{ij} & i = j \\
      0 & i \not= j 
   \end{cases}$

*This is the definition of a diagonal matrix.*

$[A^pB^q]_{ij} = [CD]_{ij} = \sum_{k = 1}^n c_{ik}d_{kj}$ *By the definition of matrix multiplication.*

$= c_{ik}d_{kj} \forall i = k = j$ *Since $c$ and $d$ are elements of diagonal matrices.*

$= c_{ij}d_{ij} \forall i = j$ Q.E.D.